# Hetzner: Load key “/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub”: invalid format

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, sftp, ssh-keys

I try SSH key authentification for Hetzner backup spaces. 
First, I generate public and private keys in my machine, then use this command:

```
server> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> storagebox_authorized_keys
```

After this command

```
echo -e "mkdir .ssh \n chmod 700 .ssh \n put storagebox_authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys \n chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys" | sftp <username>@<username>.your-storagebox.de
```

I have an error after logging sftp:

```
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
```

Debug:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for user.your-backup.de
debug1: Connecting to user.your-backup.de [2a01:4f8:b19:3000::14] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version mod_sftp
debug1: no match: mod_sftp
debug1: Authenticating to user.your-backup.de:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:EXMPL
debug1: Host 'user.your-backup.de' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EXMPL /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

UPD: content of `id_rsa.pub`:
`ssh-rsa string with slash and symbols`

Command line that generates that debug output:
`ssh -v user@user.your-backup.de`.
Content of both files identical.

UPD2: After deleting next lines in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
Host user.your-backup.de
    User u198752
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I generate new ssh-key without passphrase for key and got new error:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to user.your-backup.de [2a01:4f8:b19:3000::14] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version mod_sftp
debug1: no match: mod_sftp
debug1: Authenticating to user.your-backup.de:22 as 'u198752'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:exmpl 
debug1: Host 'user.your-backup.de' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:lexmpl /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

UPD3: I did all the steps from the beginning: created a new key pair, moved the public key to authorized_keys, returned ssh_config to its original state. Now the last line of debug output is:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:EXMPL /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Are the contents of both files, id_rsa.pub and storagebox_authorized_keys, identical?

Comment: @ChristophSommer yes, it is. I also try to copypaste it by WinSCP

Comment: @RalfFriedl `ssh-rsa string with slash and symbols`

Comment: @RalfFriedl `ssh -v user@user.your-backup.de`

Comment: @RalfFriedl get it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on your local computer, not on the Hetzner backup space.

If you don't specify an identity file when invoking `ssh`, there has to be a wrong name in one of your configuration files. It tries to load the public key as a private key.

Try

```
ssh -v -F /dev/null user@user.your-backup.de
```

For reference, compare to this command:

```
$ ssh -v -i /etc/issue user@user.your-backup.de
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
...
Load key "/etc/issue": invalid format
```

The option `-i` is used to specify the private key, so somewhere in your configuration there has to be something that tries to load the **private** key from `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, but the file contains a **public** key.

**Edit**

To address some of the confusion in your comments:

- You can create a key pair with `ssh-keygen`. This saves the public key in `id_rsa.pub` and the private key in `id_rsa` (unless you specify otherwise).
- The private key is meant to stay private and never leaves your system.
- The public part is copied to the `authorized_keys` file on the target system, not the private key.
- You should not change the common part of `ssh_config`, `Host *`, unless you know what you are doing.
- The suggestion with `-F /dev/null` was just meant to avoid loading your faulty configuration, not for real use.

Comment: Okay, how can i fix it? Is this done in the ssh config file?

Comment: If the first command works for you, then there is a problem with your configuration files. Assuming you didn't change the generic part, I would look at "/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for user.your-backup.de".

Comment: First command requested passphrase for key, but I don't know it. It's not a problem, I can generate new key-pair. I found in config next line: `Host user.your-backup.de
        User user
        IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
`.

Comment: Line 53 commented.

Comment: The `IdentityFile` should be `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, which is also the default and therefor  not necessary.

Comment: After change in `Host *` part `IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, I copypaste `id_rsa` file in `authorized_keys` manualy and it still not authentificat without password. And `ssh -v -F /dev/null user@user.your-backup.de` don't work also.

Comment: I added some points that should clarify the process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I did all the steps from the beginning: created a new key pair, moved the public key to authorized_keys, returned ssh_config to its original state. However, the error remains the same :( I will add the final output to question.

Comment: Upvoted, because you apparently solved the original problem. In my opinion the answer should have been accepted right then and a new question raised to address a *new* problem. What happened instead is [not that uncommon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310) though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same error.

> Load key "key_name": invalid format

I have solved it. I suggest to check two things:

1. If you are using `~/.ssh/config` then please check that you have specified there you private key. If you specified public key there you will ll get the error.
2. Please check your `echo $HOME`. In some OS like Ubuntu/Debian when you type:

   $ sudo bash

Your `$HOME` directory stay the same. I mean it is not `/root`. So the OS is looking for SSH keys in `/home/user/.ssh/` directory but you think it is using `/root/.ssh` directory.

So please check the output of `echo $HOME`.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the help, but I decided to use the information from [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/) lesson and it helped.

**Edit:** Use this bash script and keychain:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remote Server Rsync backup Replication Shell Script
# Local dir location
LOCALBAKPOINT=/iscsi
LOCALBAKDIR=/backups/server1.nixcraft.net.in/wwwroot
# Remote ssh server setup
SSHUER=root
SSHSERVER=server1.nixcraft.net.in
SSHBACKUPROOT=/wwwroot

# Make sure you can log in to remote server without a password
source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh 

# Make sure local backup dir exists
[ ! -d ${LOCALBAKPOINT}${LOCALBAKDIR} ] && mkdir -p ${LOCALBAKPOINT}${LOCALBAKDIR}

# Start backup 
/usr/bin/rsync --exclude '*access.log*' --exclude '*error.log*' -avz -e 'ssh ' ${SSHUER}@${SSHSERVER}:${SSHBACKUPROOT} ${LOCALBAKPOINT}${LOCALBAKDIR}

# See if backup failed or not to /var/log/messages file
[ $? -eq 0 ] && logger 'RSYNC BACKUP : Done' || logger 'RSYNC BACKUP : FAILED!'
```